# Cannot cast int to varchar in STUFF while joining select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using stuff to join results of select. The columns I need to join are not constant and could change. So I put them in a variable and prepare a dynamic query.

```
SET @sql =  N'Select @newvalues = STUFF( ( Select '','' +  ' + @columns + ' FROM #MYINSERTED FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE)
                      .value(''.'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''),1,2,'''')'
```

This query transforms into what looks like follows:

```
Select @newvalues = STUFF( 
                    ( Select ',' +  ID, CaseID, DocumentType, FileName, FileExtension, FilePath, InsertDate, InsertedBy, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy, OriginalFileName 
                    FROM #MYINSERTED FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                      .value(''.'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''),1,2,'')
```

But the first column ID is an integer and I get the following error.

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Please guide as to if there could be any workaround and I cannot cast each column individually as columns could change.

Comment: Perhaps if you described what you are trying to achieve. For example, what is the expected output of @newvalues? I think there could be a much easier way to do what you want, than to use STUFF, FOR XML PATH(''), etc.

Comment: I want to merge columns of single row returned by a select statement into a comma separated string(@newvalues).. but the only problem here is the column count be different every time..

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: @Dan Thanks dan it worked.. It was real simple if only had I given a good thought.. only a minor correction though.. appreciate it –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason to use STUFF, FOR XML PATH, etc. to merge the output of all columns into a single string. Simply make sure that all columns are explicitly cast when you construct your dynamic SQL.

How do you construct your `@columns` variable? I assume it contains something like "ID, CaseID, DocumentType, ...". You must construct a similar variable that does the explicit casting, or transform your `@columns` variable like this:

```
 SET @columnsCast = 'CAST(' + REPLACE(@columns, ',', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '', '' CAST( ') + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))'
```

This should make the `@columnsCast` variable look like this:

```
CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + CAST(CaseID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + CAST(DocumentType AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' ...
```

Then simply perform a dynamic SQL statement like this:

```
SET @sql = N'DECLARE @newvalues AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '''';
             SELECT @newvalues = @newvalues + ' + @columnsCast + ' FROM #MYINSERTED'
```

Then when you execute this expression, make sure to output `@newvalues` like this:

```
DECLARE @newvals AS VARCHAR(MAX)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@newvalues VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @newvalues=@newvals OUTPUT
SELECT @newvals
```

Comment: I get an error : Incorrect syntax near '='. Also the variable @columns is not one column but a comma separated string of columns.. So would the comparison be effective and the cast work?